# How to add value to button id using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In page it's dynamically adding the button control. The button name is 'btn'. By pressing the 'btn' button its dynamically generate 'btn1','btn2' ,'btn3'.. etc.
For eg, if I got counter value is 3, then how can I add the counter value with button(btn3). I tried the following code:

```
function AddRow(x){

         var counter = x;
          debugger;
          counter++;
          var btncount=x-1;
          var str='<div class="clsDy '+ counter +'"><label style="padding-left: 77px;"><%=GetGlobalResourceObject("ResLanguage", "Width") + "*"%>   </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" style="width: 75px; margin-left: 40px;" TextMode="SingleLine" class="txtBox param"  placeholder="cm" onchange="fnOnUpdateValidatorsNew()"  name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtWidth' + counter + '" value="" >' 

                  + '<label style="margin-left: 20px;"><%=GetGlobalResourceObject("ResLanguage", "Height") + "*"%> </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" style="width: 75px; margin-left: 44px; " name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtHeight' + counter + '"  placeholder="cm" value="" class="txtBox param" onchange="fnOnUpdateValidatorsNew()" >' 

                  + '<label style="margin-left: 24px;"><%=GetGlobalResourceObject("ResLanguage", "Lenght") + "*"%>  </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" style="width: 75px;margin-left: 40px;" placeholder="cm" TextMode="SingleLine" name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtLength' + counter + '" value="" class="txtBox param" >' 

                  + '<label style="margin-left: 24px; clear: both"><%=GetGlobalResourceObject("ResLanguage", "Weight") + "*"%> </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" TextMode="SingleLine" style="width: 75px;margin-left: 38px;"  name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtWeight' + counter + '" value="" class="txtBox param" placeholder="kg" onchange="fnOnUpdateValidatorsNew()"> <input id="btndelete('+counter+')" type="button" class="btnNew"  style ="width:40px" onclick = "Clear('+counter+')" value="-" /><input id="btnAdd('+counter+')" type="button" class="btnNew"  style ="width: 40px; margin-left: 9px;" onclick = "AddRow('+counter+')" value="+" /></div> ';
                    $("#TextBoxesGroup").append(str);
             counter++;

             //tesy
             if($('#btnAdd + counter +'))
              $('#btnAdd +btncount +').hide();
             }
        }
```

please see the //test line.

```
 //tesy
                 if($('#btnAdd + counter +'))
                  $('#btnAdd +btncount +').hide();
                 }
```

I Want to add the counter value with btnAdd.
Eg. If the counter value is 3.

```
 if($('#btnAdd3'))
              $('#btnAdd2').hide();
             }
```

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. Can you add some code (including HTML) to your question to increase clarity? What do you want to do?

Comment: Or better still, create a demo showing what's not working.

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Comment: please see question again.I modified with complete code..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
if($('#btn' + counter))
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsingii/p3yytpzf/)

Comment: please see question again.I modified with complete code..Thanks –

Comment: @jithesh - Please check my updated code and fiddle. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

A few concerns ...

1. Your counting may be off because your have `counter++` twice.
2. If the only reason you're using if is to check if the relevant element exists, you can avoid the `if` statement altogether.
3. If you must use the `if` statement (after you fix the counting), here is the correct way:

.

```
if( $('#btnAdd' + counter).length )
    $('#btnAdd' + btncount).hide();
}
//or ... shorthand
!$('#btnAdd' + counter).length || $('#btnAdd' + btncount).hide();
```

Without fixing your counting, here is an example iteration:

```
if( $('#btnAdd4').length )
    $('#btnAdd2').hide();
}
```

All you probably need is:

```
$('#btnAdd' + btncount).hide();
```

**And most importantly**,

```
.../><input id="btnAdd('+counter+')" type="button" ...
```

Should be changed to:

```
/><input id="btnAdd' + counter + '" type="button"
```